# post a job link should be target=_blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The **post a job** link - being that it goes outside the realms of SO and into the <strike>crappy</strike> ever improving careers site should open `target='_blank'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is fixed now.

Comment: Works as expected.  Thank you!