# Joel test should open target=_blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you find a job listing and you click on it midway through you'll find the <strike>notorious</strike> great Joel Test score.  The link to the Joel Test should open `target='_blank'` as we are going outside of SO in general.  Overwriting the current page doesn't seem right.

Also as much as I know this may hurt Joel's feelings, but could that page (the joel test link page) be redesigned / recreated as part of SO Jobs?  That page was done back in 2000.

Comment: I was corrected before but I always considered it to be a design goal of the SE dev team to have none of the links to open in a new tab/window. So no target attribute on links.

Comment: rene - You are headed to a totally different website, in this case, its quite normal to have it open a new window.  If you open overtop your current job you ruin the users experience as the workflow is broken.  This is pretty common in ux terms.  In the case of so q&a that may be the case but this is a totally different environment.

Comment: I'm indifferent about it but I have seen that same argument about common UX and still the request to be target=_blank to be used to be status-declined. So if I can help in getting more/different/better arguments why this is needed and to be judged on a case-by-case basis instead of one general UX rule, let's have it.

Comment: @rene - see this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312770/post-a-job-link-should-be-target-blank point is if anything goes outside the realms of the core site it should not open over top of the existing page.  You risk the chance that the whole experience for the user is broken / lost.

Comment: Ah, you have managed to start a change ;)

Comment: @rene - change is good, and in this case makes total sense for anyone looking for a job in this case.

Comment: This is a terrible change.  Clicking on a link should always open in the existing page.  If I want a new tab, I ctrl-click it.  This is standard web behavior; target=_blank breaks that.

Comment: @Brian This is anecdotal, but I don't think I've ever seen anyone else use `ctrl+click` to open a link, including other developers I work with. It may be a standard web browser function, but it is not (in my observations) a standard web user behavior. (BTW: I use the middle mouse button to open a new tab instead of `ctrl+click`. On the mice I use, clicking with the scroll wheel is the same as a middle mouse click.)

Comment: @tehDorf TBH, I usually use the middle mouse button, too.  IME mentioning that makes people start saying "Mice only have two buttons!"  Either way, the point remains:  Link behavior is the most fundamental thing on the web -- if I want to open something in the same tab, I open it in the same tab.  New tab?  New window?  These are all basic browser use tasks!  Breaking that is just annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is fixed now.